# Change color of font in dropdown of bootstrap navbar when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to change the color of the font shown in the image so that it is plainly visible.  [image: dark font on dark background]

this is a basic bootstrap 3 navbar.   here is the html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-spacer"></div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="first"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown ">
                        <a href="link1.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="link1-1.htm">Item 1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link1-2.htm">Item 1-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link1-3.htm">Item 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link2.htm">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link3.htm">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link4.htm">Item 4</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And this is what i have tried to do to change the font color

```
@media (max-width: 767) {
  .dropdown-menu > li > a{
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom .container .container-fluid .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a  {
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #b0cb36;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #b0cb36;
    background-color: #003748;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

Nothing I have tried has changed that dark font to be a lighter one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem us with your media query - you need to include the unit e.g. `@media (max-width: 767px)`

Once that is corrected, you just need to use a more specific selector to override the Bootstrap CSS, rather than using `!important`. The selectors you need to override are:

- `.dropdown-menu>li>a`
- `.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover`

Adding the `.navbar-nav` class is enough, e.g. `.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a` - you don't want to make it too specific as it makes it more difficult if you wish to override it again in future.

**Working example** (except I've removed the collapse class so we can see it in the snippet)

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: red;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: lime;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-spacer"></div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="first"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown ">
            <a href="link1.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="link1-1.htm">Item 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1-2.htm">Item 1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1-3.htm">Item 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="link2.htm">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="link3.htm">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="link4.htm">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I completely missed that it did not have the unit in the media selector.  Once I added that it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "text-danger" or whatever color you prefer. I didn't try it but I hope it works! If it does not work then add class to each li.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-spacer"></div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="first"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown ">
                        <a href="link1.htm" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-danger">
                            <li><a href="link1-1.htm">Item 1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link1-2.htm">Item 1-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="link1-3.htm">Item 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="link2.htm">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link3.htm">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link4.htm">Item 4</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```